# Complexity of polynomial interpolation

Tags: reference-request, runtime-analysis, polynomial-time, polynomials, fourier-transform

Polynomial Interpolation in the general case is $O(n^2)$ time complexity, but it can be done better in particular situations. For instance, when the polynomial can be evaluated at the complex roots of unity, it can be interpolated in $O(n\log n)$ time with the Fast Fourier Transform. Or at least, that's the only situation that I am aware of that can be done better than $O(n^2)$.

Are there any other forms of input that can be interpolated in better than $O(n^2)$ time?

I am particularly interested in knowing whether or not there is an algorithm that interpolates a polynomial from evenly spaced points (in the x-coordinate that is) that beats $O(n^2)$, because I think I've come up with something that does it in $O(n\log n)$ time.

Comment: It’s often irrelevant because interpolation with large n becomes numerically unstable. You really don’t want to put a degree 100 polynomial through 101 points.

Comment: And evenly spaced isn’t very good. Look up Chebychev or Clenshaw/Curtis (not sure about the names and spelling)

Comment: @gnasher729 It's perfectly good f.e. in Galois Fields. In particular I used it for fast Reed-Solomon codec: https://github.com/Bulat-Ziganshin/FastECC - we evaluate order-N polynomial at M points at encoding and then can restore polynomial coefficients from **any** N survived points.

Answer (score 3):

[Fast polynomial interpolation](https://www.google.com/search?q=fast%20polynomial%20interpolation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) and [Fast polynomial evaluation](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fast%20polynomial%20evaluation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) are algorithms that seem to be discovered [back in 1973](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Fast-evaluation-and-interpolation-Kung/591c828e9bc779e40afbc9d7032ed2ba0fa9de2b). They allow to interpolate/evaluate polynomial at N arbitrary points as far as field has 2N (?) roots of unity. Both are based on [Fast polynomial division](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fast%20polynomial%20division&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t). All three are $O(n\log^2 n)$ time.

Currently they are taught at university courses and I downloaded a lot of lecture notes some time ago. Unfortunately, most links are now dead. So you can download my archive from https://mega.nz/#!ugYRXIYB!T_0cKabvJpZmBNN7ym98nofPIOksqTN5XFxToSKj9Zg

Or read the only course still available at the old address:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/ST12/scribe/lect06.pdf
http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/ST12/scribe/lect07.pdf

Or just look for up-to-date notes among google search results of [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=fast%20polynomial%20interpolation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t), [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fast%20polynomial%20evaluation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) and [3](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fast%20polynomial%20division&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t). Or, yeah, try to understand the [original paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Fast-evaluation-and-interpolation-Kung/591c828e9bc779e40afbc9d7032ed2ba0fa9de2b).

Comment: So, to clarify, there are already algorithms that can interpolate a polynomial from any arbitrary set of points in $O(n\log^2 n)$, and polynomial interpolation is not in fact $O(n^2)$ in the general case?

Comment: Is it known if we can do better in case of finite fields with prime order $p$ and at interpolation points $1, 2, 3, ..., n$?

Comment: @VadimPelyushenko it's not general case - the field should have 2N roots of unity. For example GF(2^k) fields doesn't have nontrivial roots of 1 at all

Comment: @Somnium we can do better if we do interpolation/evaluation at roots of unity (instead of 1..n) - we can directly use FFT/iFFT in this case with O(n*log n) speed