# What's the fastest algorithm for polynomial interpolation in finite field with prime order at points 1, 2, 3, ..., n?

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

Suppose we have finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with prime order $p$. Can we find polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ having given values $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ at $x=1, 2, ..., n$ in less than $O(n^2)$ operations in $\mathbb{F}_p$?

There is [reference to general algorithm in another question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93936/complexity-of-polynomial-interpolation) which runs in $O(n \log^2 n)$ time, but if I understood correctly, it is not applicable to my case, because it needs $2n$ roots of unity to work (I guess for FFT).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but in some situations we can choose $p$ so it has the desired roots of unity (e.g., by making $p$ a little bigger than necessary), and then the issue doesn't come up.